# How to choose where a funcanimation file gets saved?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created an animated graph plot using Funcanimation and saving it using animation.Funcanimation.save(). Is there any way you can change/decide the location where the file is saved? Currently its saving in the project folder, but what if I wanted it to be saved in another folder within my project folder or on my desktop etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `FuncAnimation.save` accepts as the first parameter the path to the output file. You simply have to pass the path where you want to save it there.

> Docstring:
>
> Save the animation as a movie file by drawing every frame.
>
> ### Parameters
>
> filename : str
> The output filename, e.g., :file:`mymovie.mp4`.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)

# we pass the path where we want to save it
ani.save("super/path/animation.mp4")
```